# Debugging jQuery with Firebug Help/Tips

Tags: jquery, debugging

All,
I'm working on some jQuery and I'm doing it in Chrome now but I've also used Firebug before in Mozilla. What I'm trying to learn is how to do some troubleshooting/debugging. For example, I have some jQuery that when I click on something nothing happens but I'm expecting it to. When I'm in the Console for Chrome nothing shows up as being an error there is just no action. I'd like to debug this to learn why nothing is happening but not sure how to debug this type of situation properly. Any suggestions/helpful tips anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a helpful tip, it's called Firebug in Firefox and Dragonfly in Opera!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the scripts tab inside chrome dev tools.  If you have the latest chrome, click the little folder icon at the top left and then open the .js file of interest.  From there you can set breakpoints and debug etc.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts